# Display one-by-one sentence on the Label (iOS swift)

Tags: swift, label

I have a ViewController with a label and an a button.
When I press the button, I'd want a sentence to be displayed on the label field. After pressing the button again, another sentence is displayed...etc

```
func answerButtonTapped(send: UIButton)
{ 
    var question = questionField.text 
    var i = 0 var listOfQuestions = ["Who is Arnold?", "Who is Kevin?", "Who is Liu?"] 
    for (i=0; i<=listOfQuestions.count; i++)
    { 
        questionField.text = "(listOfQuestions[i])" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you edit your question to include your code?

Comment: @IBAction func answerButtonTapped(send: UIButton){
        
        var question = questionField.text
        var i        = 0
        
        
        var listOfQuestions = ["Who is Arnold?", "Who is Kevin?", "Who is Liu?"]
        
  
        for (i=0;  i<=listOfQuestions.count;  i++){
             questionField.text = "\(listOfQuestions[i])"
            
         
        }
    }

Comment: Use the edit button to add your code to the question.

Comment: What does the label say right now when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I don't have a computer to test it on at the moment but I'm 99% sure this is the answer.*

Just change this line of code `questionField.text = "(listOfQuestions[i])"` to `questionField.text = listOfQuestions[i]`.